# How to crop images using OpenCV without knowing the exact coordinates?

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to crop an image of a piece of card/paper or such so that the card/paper is in focus. I tried the below code but the problem is that it works only when the object in question is alone in the picture. If it is a blank background with nothing else in it- the cropping is flawless, otherwise it does not work as expected.

I am attempting create a system which crops different kinds of images and puts them through a classifier and then extracts text from them.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
filenames = "img.jpg"
img = cv2.imread(filenames)
blurred = cv2.blur(img, (3,3))
canny = cv2.Canny(blurred, 50, 200)

## find the non-zero min-max coords of canny
pts = np.argwhere(canny>0)
y1,x1 = pts.min(axis=0)
y2,x2 = pts.max(axis=0)

## crop the region
cropped = img[y1:y2, x1:x2]

filename_cropped = filenames.split('.')
filename_cropped[0] = filename_cropped[0] + '_cropped'
filename_cropped = '.'.join(filename_cropped)

cv2.imwrite(filename_cropped, cropped)
```

An sample image that works is

[image: sample img]

Something that does not work is

[image: sample img]
Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

The first image works because the entire images besides your target is empty. Canny will also give other results when there is more in the image.

If you are looking for those specific cards I suggest you try to use some colour filtering first. You can try to filer for the blue/purple hue of the card.

Increasing the canny threshold could also work, but you will always still be finding the hand as well in this image unless you add some colour filtering.

You can also try  [Sobel edge detection](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/d2c/tutorial_sobel_derivatives.html) . This will probably highlight the instant edges of the card pretty well. But then again, it will also show the hand, so you can't just take all the Sobel/Canny outputs. You need to add processing before it that isolates the card, or after it that can find the rectangular shape of the card in the sobel/canny.

Comment: Hi, I am able to get the edge using Sobel, however could you tell me how to crop it?